# Derivative Graph Points Interpretation and Understanding Local Extrma Values

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For this graph, y=f'(x)

[image]

Q1. At x=1 f(x) has a...

Answer Choices:

local maximum
point of inflection
local minimum
point of nondifferentiability
point of discontinuity

I'm not sure how to answer this one. If the graph above was f(x), then I know at x=1, you can't take the derivative. However, I am not sure when the graph is f'(x)

Q2. Over the interval (-4,4), how many local maxima does f(x) have.

I drew a number line for this. I labeled all the points at which f'(x)=0. I then found x=0 is the only local extrema because the sign changes from + to -. Is this correct?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Question 1:}$

At $x=1, f$  clearly cannot achieve a maximum or minimum because $f'$ is continuous at that point and nonzero. $f$ is clearly differentiable and therefore continuous (differentiability implies continuity) at $x=1$ because the point appears on the graph of $f'.$ A point of inflection occurs when curvature changes signs. For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, $ this means that the derivative switches from decreasing to increasing or vice versa. This is of course what is happening on the graph.

$\textbf{Question 2: }$

Be careful using the word extrema as it refers to both maxima and minima. Local extrema occur at $x=-3,0,\text{ and }2$ but you are correct in your analysis that $x=0$ is the only maximum because $f$ switches from increasing to decreasing.